# Bug with notifications: I'm getting notified of two items every day

Tags: bug, notifications, top-bar

I'm always getting these two notifications every single day:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1187497

https://stackoverflow.com/election

[image]

Comment: You mean you read the notification, the red notification alert on your inbox goes away and then it returns the next day with the same 2 items shown as unread?

Comment: exactly. opening the popup should be enough to flag them as read, right? then they disappear but after some hours they appear again

Comment: That's how it works for me.  The only time it doesn't go away is when I have multiple tabs open, get the notification in all of the open tabs, then read it in one tab (where they get marked as read).  The notification won't get marked as read in the other tabs until you refresh the page or nagivate to another page.

Comment: well, i might had multiple tabs open, i will check but i believe there's more causing it. thanks